# Buscar dados no MYSQL e mostrar no gráfico Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pessoa!

Estou começando na área de desenvolvimento e tenho no momento, a necessidade de trabalhar com a biblioteca de gráficos javascript Highcharts. Porém, não tenho conhecimento de como buscar estes dados no MYSQL e apresentar no gráfico, em minha máquina tenho o banco de dados "Sakila" que vou usar para gerar os dados no gráfico com intuito de aprendizado.

Venho aqui buscar conhecimento necessário e boas práticas para com o uso de desenvolvimento Web.

Segue abaixo o código Javascritp do gráfico a ser implementado para buscar os dados no "Sakila do MYSQL".

```js
<html>
<head>
<title>Highcharts Tutorial</title>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="width: 550px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<script language="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   var title = {
      text: 'Monthly Average Temperature'   
   };
   var subtitle = {
      text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
   };
   var xAxis = {
      categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
         'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
   };
   var yAxis = {
      title: {
         text: 'Temperature (\xB0C)'
      },
      plotLines: [{
         value: 0,
         width: 1,
         color: '#808080'
      }]
   };   

   var tooltip = {
      valueSuffix: '\xB0C'
   }

   var legend = {
      layout: 'vertical',
      align: 'right',
      verticalAlign: 'middle',
      borderWidth: 0
   };

   var series =  [
      {
         name: 'Tokyo',
         data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2,
            26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
      }, 
      {
         name: 'New York',
         data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8,
            24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
      }, 
      {
         name: 'Berlin',
         data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6,
            17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
      }, 
      {
         name: 'London',
         data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 
            16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
      }
   ];

   var json = {};

   json.title = title;
   json.subtitle = subtitle;
   json.xAxis = xAxis;
   json.yAxis = yAxis;
   json.tooltip = tooltip;
   json.legend = legend;
   json.series = series;

   $('#container').highcharts(json);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O exemplo abaixo gera um [gráfico de setores](http://www.profmarcovargas.com.br/2012/08/grafico-de-setores.html) a partir de um back-end PHP, recebendo um parâmetro de um `input` do tipo text, que é passado para a query para você filtrar no banco de dados se quiser, se não for necessário é só remover tudo que está relacionado ao formulário e também o `bindParam` do PDO além da cláusula `where` do SQL :)

**PHP:**

```html
<?php

//recebe o parametro vindo do JavaScript

$param = $_GET['param'];

//abre conexao PDO

try {
    $con = new PDO("mysql:host=MeuServidor;dbname=MeuBancoDeDados", $usuario, $senha);
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    print_r('Error: ' . $ex->getMessage());
}

$query = "select Coluna_1, sum(valor) as valor "
        . "from MinhaTabela "
        . "where Parametro = :param";

$prepare = $con->prepare($query);

try{
    $prepare->bindParam(':param', $param, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $prepare->execute;

    $resultado = $prepare->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    //retorna o JSON
    echo json_encode($resultado, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    print_r('Error: ' . $ex->getMessage());
}
```

**Marcação HTML:**

```
<input id="meu-input" placeholder="Digite um filtro...">

<div id="grafico-setor"></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```js
'use strict';
$(function () {
    var meu_filtro = $('#meu-input'),
            param = $('#meu-input').val();

    //atualiza a variável passada como parâmetro e a função toda vez que um caracter é adicionado ou removido do filtro
    meu_filtro.on('keyup paste change focus blur keydown', function () {
        param = $('#meu-input').val();
        hc_grafico_setor(param);
    });
  
    //define a função que gera o gráfico
    function hc_grafico_setor(param) {
        $.getJSON('link/para/o/json.php', {
            //parametros
            param: param
        }, function (data) {
            //cria um objeto Highcharts chamado de 'chart'
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: "grafico-setor", //#id da div que vai renderizar o gráfico
                    type: 'pie', // tipo do grafico. Pode ser setado em series também
                  
                    //para o grafico ocupar todo o espaço. Pode ser removido
                    marginTop: 0,
                    marginBottom: 0,
                    marginRight: 0,
                    marginLeft: 0
                },
                credits: {
                    enabled: false,  //Setar para true se quiser mostrar os créditos
                    text: 'Quem fez o gráfico...'
                },
                title: {
                    text: "Títuo do meu gráfico",
                    verticalAlign: 'top', //alinha o titulo verticalmente
                    floating: true
                },
                tooltip: {
                    useHTML: true, //formatar a tooltip usando elementos HTML
                  
                    //o Highcharts tem uma função própria para formatar numeros: Highcharts.numberFormat()
                    formatter: function () {
                        return '<div style="text-align: center"><b>' + this.point.name + '</b><br>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.percentage, 1) + ' %<br />' +
                                'R$ ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.y) +
                                '<br />Total: R$ ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.total, 2) + '</div>';
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: false //desabilita a legenda. Setar para true se quiser habilitar a legenda
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        innerSize: 0 //se quiser criar um donut, aumentar esse valor
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                        data: data, //dados vindos do JSON
                        size: '100%'
                    }]
            });
        });
    };
    //inicializa a função que gera o grafico
    hc_grafico_setor(param);
});
```

**Plugins necessários:**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
```

Comment: Humn?! Eu não sou Daniel!

Comment: Eduardo Almeida!  1. Crio uma tabela no MYSQL chamada "primeiro_grafico"                                                                                                                                                                           CREATE TABLE `primeiro_grafico` (
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `val` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

/*Dados para a tabela `primeiro_grafico` */                                                    
      insert  int para os dados da tabela.

Comment: 2. Recuperar dados como JSON usando PHP  - Obs: Salvo o php com o códifo separdo do "Index.php" chamado (data;php).                                    <?php

//recebe o parametro vindo do JavaScript

$param = $_GET['param'];

//abre conexao PDO

try {
    $con = new PDO("mysql:host=MeuServidor;dbname=MeuBancoDeDados", $usuario, $senha);
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

Comment: 3. Implemento os Plugins necessários no index.php                   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Highcharts Pie Chart</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">    -  Juntamente com o Javascript 'use strict';
$(function () {     - Faço referencia ao data.php com o código: $.getJSON("data.php", function(json) {
    options.series[0].data = json;
          chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

Comment: Eduardo Almeida!  Me corrija seu eu estiver errado, por favor.

Answer (score 1):

fluxo, html+js(estrutura dos gráficos definidos), requisição ajax a um arquivo php, arquivo php select no banco echo json_encode(dados), de volta ao js onde fica os gráficos como estrutura de objetos você implementa os dados. OBS:

```js
var title = {
      text: 'Monthly Average Temperature'   
   };
   var subtitle = {
      text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
   };
   var xAxis = {
      categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
         'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
   };
   var yAxis = {
      title: {
         text: 'Temperature (\xB0C)'
      },
      plotLines: [{
         value: 0,
         width: 1,
         color: '#808080'
      }]
   };
```

Essa estrura vai ser construído no json...